# Transfering complex map symbology from ArcGIS Desktop using AutoCad Map object classes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, autocad-map

I'm trying to find the best way to transfer maps form ArcGIS to AutoCad Map. In ArcGIS map model is  separated from it's representation. View is created by applying symbology and representation rules to  underlying model. As far as I know this approach could be achieved in AutoCad Map using object definition classes. So I looking for a way to create complex topographic map symbology(like in ArcGIS) using AutoCad Map object classes. Official AutoDesk help describes this very poor. Is it really possible? Could someone provide links to some articles, how-tows about this issue?

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question but a good place to start is importing your attribute data as Autodesk Object Data. Object Data is relatively simple to setup in AutoCAD and makes the transformation from CADD to GIS very efficient. Object Data can then be exported from AutoCAD as attributes of the feature (fields within the exported shapefile).

Answer (score 1):

We have faced similar problem during conversion of some ArcGIS data to MapInfo. MapInfo's common practice is to store representation together with geometry data.

1. Every type of objects was assigned a `code` - in this way we've applied classification (i.e. small river, pedestrian road, etc.)
2. We have converted data to MapInfo format. All symbology that we had in ArcGIS was lost in MapInfo.
3. Then we created a tool and style library for MapInfo. This tool was iterating all objects on the map in MapInfo check its `code` and applied appropriate symbology from the library. So, we actually need to run it once, to write symbology inside object.

You can try this way for your data in AutoCAD in case if you will fail to manage AutoCAD Map object classes.

Comment: We also use codes to apply feature representation rules(it is common practice). Question is about building symbol library with AutoCad Map OOB feature - object classes. (I think you know how, complex map symbology is in ex USSR topographic maps).

Comment: Indeed, it is definitely not an "easy-use" styles in GIS world...